# Multiple Instances of React Application on the Same Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

Hello I have a React Redux application built and ejected from Create React App.  I'd like to render this application twice on the same webpage.  Our main webpage does not use React, but these specific portions will.  I have built the application and it renders fine when I only render it once, but when I render it twice on two separate dom nodes, values I change in the second application get updated on the first.  It appears to be sharing state between the two application.

From my research, this appears to be a perfectly doable objective.  I've read this may be caused by the webpack build as well, although I would like to avoid having to include multiple of the same scripts on a page just to create a unique build ([see this link](https://medium.jonasbandi.net/hosting-multiple-react-applications-on-the-same-document-c887df1a1fcd)).  I'm looking for help in rendering two unique instances of my application.  The code below is the root of my application:

```
const one = document.querySelector('[data-dfa=local]');
const two = document.querySelector('[data-dfa=local2]');

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <FieldAppointment appId='one' />
  </Provider>, one);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <FieldAppointment appId='two' />
  </Provider>, two);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same store for both instances.  When something in one application updates the store, they both recieve that change.  Maybe break it up into two separate stores?:

```js
const store1 = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

const store2 = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store1}>
    <FieldAppointment appId='one' />
  </Provider>, one);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store2}>
    <FieldAppointment appId='two' />
  </Provider>, two);
```